# Grey Render in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

My project was going great, then all of a sudden, I only get a grey render screen using Eevee. I've tried everything and have spent hours researching and [Link to blender file](https://inlbox.box.com/s/pmoxv2w8r71rg2v6hm252uzhfkqn57ym)trying to figure out why it is only rendering a grey box.

I've played with camera distance settings, World Settings, resolution settings, Nodes etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I think it has to do with the "cube" that you have displayed as wireframe. How did you make it this way? It has no attached material, and even changing viewport display type back to textured or solid, still leaves it as a wireframe "box". Regardless, removing it fixes the render.

Comment: Thanks for the input Chris, but no. I do not have any hidden objects

Comment: Thanks again Chris. This "cube" is a Domain so that the smoke and flame render inside of it. You are right however, if it is removed then it does render correctly but there is no smoke or flame. Very interesting though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I didn't even look at the physics properties to see that it was a domain. There could be a few things going on, but to be honest, I haven't done any real domain work since 2.82, and a bunch of stuff was different then, so I can't remember how to make the domain properly "invisible".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that making my own "domain" (didn't use the "quick Effects") was the culprit. I think that there may be more to it than that, but my issue is solved for now. So if smoke and or flame is needed, make your domain, then add "quick effects".